# Rookie question regarding studs in garage ceiling

Tags: ceiling, garage, studs

Good afternoon,

Im trying to hang two hooks in my garage ceiling to hang a bicycle.  I used a magnetic stud finder and marked a bunch of points where it stuck.

To confirm, the studfinder is just picking up the screws correct?  How do I determine where the beams run to drill into?  Do the beams run up and down between the marking from the wall?  Is this where the beams run:  [image]

Here's a photo of where I marked what the studfinder found.  They're all roughly a foot apart, give or take an inch.  The idea was to drill into two of the spots and horizontally hang the bike.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: FYI Rookie. Studs are in walls and ceilings have joist's or trusses.  Easier to mount a 2x4 into and spanning the joist's and then place the hooks at the correct distance apart on the 2x4. Magnetic finders find metal so it did it job. Bonus is the metal screw you found is screwed into wood, joist or truss.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Thanks.  Was editing as you responded.  Does my edited image make sense as to where the beams run?  If so, then I already have two that would be the proper distance for the bike tires.  If that's the case, is there still a need to run a two 2x4?  If not, what the method I should use to find where the beams run between the joists.  Thanks

Comment: As long as you have structure were you want it you are ok. You need to be sure that you are screwing into the **exact middle of the joist** and **pre-drill a pilot hole of the appropriate size** for the hook you are using.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a method to determine that I'm drilling in the middle of the joist?

Comment: **Yes but that costs extra**, just use a small drill bit and drill to each side until you no longer hit structure and you can figure out where the middle is.